# Equation of line of reflection

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I have equations of line 1 and line 2 as b(1,2,−2)′ and c(2,3,6)′ respectively (in vector equation form) where b and c are real numbers. And the point P(18,27,54) on line 2. Given that line 1 is the reflection of line 2 about a third line 3, the aim is to find a possible vector equation of line 3.

So my first step was to find the foot of perpendicular F from P to line 1: find the vector PF=OF−OP then dot product it with the direction vector of line 1. Equating to 0, I get (−4,−8,8)′ as the position vector of F. I also know the origin is the point of intersection between line 1 and 2. I must be missing something simple but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Is _P_ a common point for lines 1 and 2? If not, what point is line2 passing through?

Comment: P is only on line 2. The only common point of the two lines is the origin.

Comment: Why do we need _P_ then?

Comment: @ja72 We don’t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lines are reflections of each other in some third line, then that line must be one of their angle bisectors. The direction vectors of the two given lines are $\mathbf v=(1,2,-2)$ and $\mathbf w=(2,3,6)$ and a pair of vectors that bisect the angles between them are $$\mathbf b_1=\|\mathbf w\|\mathbf v+\|\mathbf v\|\mathbf w=7(1,2,-2)+3(2,3,6)=(13,23,4) \\ \mathbf b_2=\|\mathbf w\|\mathbf v-\|\mathbf v\|\mathbf w=7(1,2,-2)-3(2,3,6)=(1,5,-32).$$ The lines intersect at the origin, therefore the two possible lines of reflection are $\lambda(13,23,4)$ and $\mu(1,5,-32)$, $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Is b= |w|v + |v|w a standard formula for finding the vector that bisect the angle between two lines?

Comment: @xiangqi Yes. If you have two vectors of the same length, it should be obvious from the rhombus that they form that the two angle bisectors are their sum and difference. Cross-multiplying by lengths is a simple way to produce two equal-length vectors from two arbitrary vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The direction vector of line $3$ should be a linear combination of $v_1=(1,2,-2)$ and $v_2=(2,3,6)$. Let it be $v_3=tv_1+(1-t)v_2$ for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

$v_3$ makes the same angle with $v_1$ and $v_2$. So, we have

$$\frac{v_1\cdot v_3}{|v_1||v_3|}=\frac{v_2\cdot v_3}{|v_2||v_3|}$$

$$\frac{tv_1\cdot v_!+(1-t)v_1\cdot v_2}{|v_1|}=\frac{tv_1\cdot v2+(1-t)v_2\cdot v_2}{|v_2|}$$

$t$ and hence $v_3$ can be easily found.

Comment: Ahh I see. But why can we use t and 1-t or how do we know the coefficients add up to 1? My instinct would be to use a and b but then we are solving for two variables instead of one t.

Comment: Do you mean $v_3=\frac{av_1+bv_2}{a+b}$? If we let $t=\frac{a}{a+b}$, then we have $\frac{b}{a+b}=1-t$.  It is more convenient to use a single parameter.

Comment: ahh but why is v3 in the above form and not just av1+bv2

Comment: Yes, you can. But then you will have two unknowns and only one equation.  You will be able to find infinitely many possible $v_3$, all parallel to the one you can find with my solution. So actually you can let $v_3=av_1+bv_2$.

Comment: Is there an approach that makes use of the fact that (18, 27, 54) is on line two and so the foot of perpendicular from that point to line 1 is (-4, -8, 8) then somehow find the line of reflection by some geometrical approach?

Comment: I don't think we can do that, as we have to deal with symmetry. The picture you described seems not related to symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality you can align a coordinate system on the plane that contains the two lines. If the lines are skewed then they cannot be mirrors of each other.

In 2D the problem is simple.

If you have two lines in equation form $a_1 x+b_1 y + c_1=0$ and $a_2 x+b_2 y + c_2=0$ then the mirror line (bisection) is simply defined by

$$ (a_1+a_2) x + (b_1+b_2) y + (c_1+c_2) = 0 $$

Given that you have two directions ${\bf e}_1 = \pmatrix{1&2&-2}$, ${\bf e}_2 = \pmatrix{2&3&6}$ and a point ${\bf P}=\pmatrix{18&27&54}$ and can do something similar in 3D too, using so called Plücker line coordinates.

In general, point ${\bf P}_1$ belongs to one line, and ${\bf P}_2$ to the other line. The Plücker line coordinates for the two lines are

$$\matrix{ {\bf L}_1 = \left[ \matrix{ {\bf e}_1 \\ {\bf P}_1 \times {\bf e}_1 } \right] & {\bf L}_2 = \left[ \matrix{ {\bf e}_2 \\ {\bf P}_2 \times {\bf e}_2 } \right]}$$

The Plücker line coordinates for the bisector is simply

$$ {\bf M} ={\bf L}_1+{\bf L}_2= \left[ \matrix{ {\bf e}_1+{\bf e}_1 \\ {\bf P}_1 \times {\bf e}_1+{\bf P}_2 \times {\bf e}_2  } \right]  $$

The vector equation for the bisector is based on the point ${\bf R}$ on line ${\bf M}$ closest to the origin

$$ {\bf R} = \frac{ \left( {\bf e}_1 + {\bf e}_2\right) \times \left({\bf P}_1 \times {\bf e}_1+{\bf P}_2 \times {\bf e}_2 \right)}
{\| \left( {\bf e}_1 + {\bf e}_2\right) \|^2 } $$

Now the equation of the line is $$\boxed{{\bf Q}(t) = {\bf R} + \left( {\bf e}_1 + {\bf e}_2\right) t}$$

---

**Edit 1**

In this case both lines pass through the origin, with ${\bf P}_1=\pmatrix{0&0&0}$ and ${\bf P}_2=\pmatrix{0&0&0}$. This simplifies the problem since $${\bf R}=\pmatrix{0&0&0}$$ also.

$$\boxed{{\bf Q}(t) = \left( {\bf e}_1 + {\bf e}_2\right) t}$$